# Upload JPG file to Google Drive throwing System.UnauthorizedAccessException Access to the path 'c:\foldername' is denied

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to upload a JPG from my local drive to Google Drive. I set up OAuth 2.0 Client IDs on Google Clouds APIs and Services. I added Everyone group to that folder. Also, grant full control permission.
But, it still throws the following error when I run the program.

> "Exception has occurred: CLR/System.UnauthorizedAccessException An
> unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
> occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Access to the path
> 'c:\folderName' is denied.'

The error throws on the following line

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath,
                           FileMode.Open))
                {
                    // Create a new file, with metadata and stream.
                    request = service.Files.Create(
                        fileMetadata, stream, "image/jpeg");
                    request.Fields = "id";
                    request.Upload();
                }
```

Thank you for your help.

Here is my code:

```
    namespace DocUploader
{
    class Program
    {
        static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
        static string ApplicationName = "App Name";

        static string filePath = "c:\\folderName";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                UserCredential credential;
                // Load client secrets.
                using (var stream =
                       new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    string credPath = "token.json";
                    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                        Scopes,
                        "user",
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                    Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
                }

                // Create Drive API service.
                var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName
                });

                // Upload file photo.jpg on drive.
                var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
                {
                    Name = "photo.jpg"
                };
                FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
                // Create a new file on drive.
                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath,
                           FileMode.Open))
                {
                    // Create a new file, with metadata and stream.
                    request = service.Files.Create(
                        fileMetadata, stream, "image/jpeg");
                    request.Fields = "id";
                    request.Upload();
                }

                var file = request.ResponseBody;
                // Prints the uploaded file id.
                Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + file.Id);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (e is AggregateException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Credential Not found");
                }
                else if (e is FileNotFoundException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("File not found");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The user account running the program doesn't have permission to the folder C:\foldername, that is the root cause. Or your program is running in some sort of a sandbox, and so doesn't have access to that folder. For e.x Windows Store apps can only access AppData\Roaming folder

Comment: I am running on VS code. Also, I ran a simple code on deleting file in that folder. The file is deleted and no error. class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var path = "c:\\folderName\\readonly.txt";
        try
        {
            File.Delete(path);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user you are running your code from does not have access to files stored in c:\folderName.

beyond that i suspect that "c:\folderName";  is in fact the name of the folder. I dont think that the following will be able to load a FileStream for a folder.

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
```

Upload Quickstart.

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

// Installed file credentials from google developer console.
const string credentialsJson = @"C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Credentials\credentials.json";

// used to store authorization credentials.
var userName = "user";

// scope of authorization needed from the user
var scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive };

// file to upload

var filePath = @"C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Data\image.png";
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
var folderToUploadTo = "root";


var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.FromFile(credentialsJson).Secrets,
    scopes,
    userName,
    CancellationToken.None).Result;


// Create the  Drive service.
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Daimto Drive upload Quickstart"
});


// Upload file photo.jpg on drive.
var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
{
    Name = fileName,
    Parents = new List<string>() { folderToUploadTo }
};

var fsSource = File.OpenRead(filePath);

// Create a new file, with metadatafileName and stream.
var request = service.Files.Create(
    fileMetadata, fsSource, "image/jpeg");
request.Fields = "id";

var results = await request.UploadAsync(CancellationToken.None);

if (results.Status == UploadStatus.Failed)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading file: {results.Exception.Message}");
}

// the file id of the new file we created
var fileId = request.ResponseBody?.Id;

Console.WriteLine($"fileId {fileId}");

Console.ReadLine();
```

code slightly altered from: [How to upload to Google Drive API from memory with C#](https://www.daimto.com/how-to-upload-to-google-drive-api-from-memory-with-c/)